# Visa visitor, my bagages and check-in the first flight

Tags: visas, usa, transit, vietnamese-citizens

I'm a student in Canada and this is first time I’m going to travel for long distance from Montreal to Hanoi (VN). I booked a ticket flight of Japan airline, Montreal-Chicago-Tokyo-Hanoi. I will transit at Chicago ORD. I have a visa visitor USA, it's possible to pass Security of airports?

Answer (score 4):

Most US airports *require* that you pass security when you are transferring between international flights.  Your visitor visa will enable you to do this, provided, of course, that is has not expired.

Because you have a visa, you should not apply for ESTA, which is only for those traveling under the visa waiver program (VWP).

However, as noted by blackbird57 in a comment, Montreal is one of several airports in the world where travelers clear US customs and immigration at the *departure* airport instead of on arrival.  The transfer will therefore be handled in Chicago as a domestic-to-international transfer, and your bags ought to be checked through to Japan.

(I do not know whether you will need to clear customs with your bags in Tokyo, however.)

Comment: @VũViệtDũng you're most welcome.  Please accept it if you think it is the best one.  (Obviously, it is the best answer at the moment, because it is the only answer.  You can change the accepted answer later, if a better one comes along.)

Comment: yes I'm very happy for your information. phoog . I have an other question, can you help me phoog. I'm going to Chicago ORD from Montreal by American airline operated and then, I will use Japan airline to go to Narita (Tokyo). So, in Chicago ORD, I will have to move my checked-baggage once more, check-in to next flight?  Best regards!

Comment: @VũViệtDũng that ought to be a separate question (and has probably been asked before, but I couldn't find it as such).  But the answer is yes, that is the general procedure at US airports.  You not only have to claim your bags and re-check them, but you have to clear customs before you re-check them.

Comment: sory phoog, this my first question. Many thanks! nice day

Comment: I would add to that, since the OP is flying out of Montreal I know for fact they will pass US immigration in YUL, the OP won't have to do anything in Chicago in fact

Comment: @VũViệtDũng please check the edited answer, thanks.  You ought not to have to clear US customs and immigration in Chicago, since you will do that in Montreal.

Comment: Thanks phoog and blackbird57 . I noted. So I think that my checked-baggage is going to pass through the airports intermediate to the destination of this trip because it's the same airline company.

Comment: @VũViệtDũng that is my understanding.  But since I have not done a trip like this myself, if I were in your shoes, I would be prepared for the possibility of having to claim and check my bags in Chicago.  I would discuss it with the staff checking me in in Montreal.  If they did not mention what I needed to do in Chicago, I'd ask.

Comment: if they answered, pls tell me know also! thanks advance  phoog

Comment: @VũViệtDũng I never asked.  I was saying what I ***would*** do ***if*** I were in your place.  As I noted, I have never done a trip like this.  All my international travel involving the US has either been to or from the US, never through it.

Comment: I was wrong to understand your comment, I will prepare for two possibility possible coming.